# AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_excel'

Tags: pandas, python-3.5

I am using python 3.5 and pandas <1.0 version. OS : Ubuntu 16.04

Getting below error when adding style to xlsx file using pandas.

excel_data_df = pd.read_excel(workbook, engine='xlrd')

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_excel'

However this works well when pandas newest version 1.0.3 installed
but not working with 0.25 or 0.18 version.

I tried upgrading version of pandas to 1.0.3 on python3.5 but getting below error

Collecting pandas Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2f/79/f236ab1cfde94bac03d7b58f3f2ab0b1cc71d6a8bda3b25ce370a9fe4ab1/pandas-1.0.3.tar.gz Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info: Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in File "/tmp/pip-build-d_rfkjs6/pandas/setup.py", line 42 f"numpy >= {min_numpy_ver}", ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

---

I think this is due to literal f" only support in =>python3.6.
Is there any way i can upgrade pandas to latest version for python3.5?

Comment: What happens if you upgrade Pandas to the latest version (1.0.3)?

Comment: Getitng error   setup.py egg_info: Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in File "/tmp/pip-build-d_rfkjs6/pandas/setup.py", line 42 f"numpy >= {min_numpy_ver}", ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax